# Phase 2 equalization for downstream port in PCIe

Tags: pcie

Could you please clarify the following?

In phase 2 equalization, upstream port evaluates downstream port transmitter. In these process first upstream port sends preset values to down stream port. Then how the downstream port gets LF and FS values from its PHY to check whether coefficient values are legal as it is not aware of FS and LF values for the new preset values proposed by upstream port.

Similarly after evaluating preset values, upstream port evaluates co-efficient values.then how these coefficients are related to the preset values agreed on by both upstream and downstream port.and on what basis they can be increased or decreased by upstream port. And whether they need to follow the below rules by upstream port? If they need to follow means how FS and LF values are obtained for new coefficient values that are proposed?

|C -1 | ≤ Floor (FS/4)

|C -1 | + |C -2 | + C 0 + |C +1 | = FS

C 0 − |C -1 | + |C -2 | − |C +1 | ≥ LF